# Detecting change in a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, events, object, detect, watch

I found this gist to detect changes on specified fiels of a object : https://gist.github.com/3138469

But it bind an event only on one field.

Someone know a function or a tricks to detect change on an entire Javascript Object ?

Comment: I like to use [Watch.js](https://gist.github.com/1627705). Is that gist in your question taken from Watch.js?

Comment: Aouch, thanks a lot for this amazing gist ! Please post the answer and I will accept it. Thanks !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**2019 Update:** These days this can be achieved using [Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in a much more efficient manner. The [on-change library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/on-change) uses the Proxy API behind the scene to make this even easier.

**2012 Update:** I've just noticed that the author of Watch.js is referencing a library with much broader browsers' support. [MultiGetSet.JS](https://gist.github.com/2956493)

When I want to achieve this I usually use [Watch.js](https://gist.github.com/1627705), you can watch a whole object or one attribute.

Comment: Thanks for updating this answer twice although last time about 8 years had passed. People like you make SO valuable. ✌️

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible, you can only define getters/setters for individual properties.

Yet, there is a draft for [`Proxy`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies) objects which could do that. Today, it is only [supported in Firefox' Javascript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using watch.js. it just detect the changes of an object or the attributes of the object. It DOESNT detect if we add an attribute to the object or change a new added attribute...