# Lookup new Object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting change in a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578377/detecting-change-in-a-javascript-object)

Is there any reliable, cross-browser way to detect or "read", new property-names for an object when they get assigned ?

For instance:

```
var obj = {};

obj.newProperty = true;
```

I'd like to intercept that process and retrieve `"newProperty"`. My ideas so far are these:

- use ES5 getter functions ?
- use Object.watch ?
- use a setInterval to check for new properties ?

I think Object.watch is only available in Firefox, so that actually is no real option. What I need is something like "Mutation events" for native Javascript objects. Help ?

Comment: This functionality is coming with proxies in ES6 (next year).